# Visual Studio 2022: Adding Controller option is not available

Tags: visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022, I want to add a Controller function to my project.

I did **right click** my Controllers folder. After that, I clicked on **Add**. A menu opens. But adding the Controller is not available (see the image below).

[image]

The only options that are available for me are New File, Add New Item..., New Folder, New EditorConfig.

I checked out the Microsoft tutorial and they have many more options there. Check out the first image on this page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-controller?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Their options start with Controller .... and end with New EditorConfig.

What am I missing? Is there something that I should install or enable?

Comment: There's a lot more missing.  Go back to the VS Installer and ensure you've selected the web development workload.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the "ASP.NET and web development" workload but it did not resolve my issues. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: The screenshot shows that you've clicked the "Show All Files" Solution Explorer toolbar button.  Probably to find something named "Controllers".  Not sure what it does to the context menu, click that button again to switch back to the project view.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what the problem is but i think you should open you .sln file for it to work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).